# In a pandas dataframe, how do I check if two strings exist on same row but in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have been trying to figure out how to write the simplest if statement in order to check if the string "A" exist in the rootID and "B" exist in the parentID in any of the rows. I then want to remove that row. In the following dataframe I would have wanted to remove row 0 in that case.

```
                     rootID   parentID    jobID  time
                  0    A         B          D    2019-01-30 14:33:21.339469
                  1    E         F          G    2019-01-30 14:33:21.812381
                  2    A         C          D    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
                  3    E         E          F    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
                  4    E         F          G    2019-01-30 16:33:21.812381
```

I know how to check if one element exists such as

```
   if df['rootID'].str.contains("A").any()
```

but how do I do it when I need to check for two different strings in two columns?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with masks chained by `|` for `bitwise OR` and `~` for invert boolean masks.

If need check substrings:

```
m1 = ~df['rootID'].str.contains("A")
m2 = ~df['parentID'].str.contains("B")
```

If need check strings use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
m1 = df['rootID'].ne("A")
m2 = df['parentID'].ne("B")

#alternatives
#m1 = df['rootID'] != "A"
#m2 = df['parentID'] != "B"
```

---

```
df = df[m1 | m2]

print (df)
  rootID parentID jobID                        time
1      E        F     G  2019-01-30 14:33:21.812381
2      A        C     D  2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
3      E        E     F  2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381
4      E        F     G  2019-01-30 16:33:21.812381
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.query('rootID != "A" | parentID != "B"')
```

Comment: Thank you once again for helping me. How do I afterwards select that row and delete it from the original dataframe?

Comment: So in order to implement this correctly. Do I first define m1 and m2 and then afterwards test it by "if m1 and m2:"?

Comment: @Kspr - No, you can use `df = df[~df['rootID'].str.contains("A") | ~df['parentID'].str.contains("B")]` and similar, only if more conditions it is more readable

Comment: The thing is I need to check every time this occurs and increment a timer every time. So I would want an if case, so that I can increment the counter and then remove the row.

Comment: why don't you just count how many such rows are there? (hint: the booleans created can answer that easily)  @Kspr

Comment: Also, the A and B have to be one the same row in order for it to be removed. So I want to keep a row which is [A,C,D] or [E,B,F]

Comment: Well I will have live data fed into the script. Whenever a row which already exists is there, I will replace it with the new row and increment a counter which says "updated"

Comment: @Kspr - Hmmm, I think the best is create new question with this requirements, it is more complicated like original question. Thank you.

Comment: good Luck , when I saw op keeping adding the conditions , I usually just step away

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear and leaving out conditions. I will post a new one tomorrow when I am allowed to post again. Thank you for the help @Wen-Ben and jezrael